# Numpy Neural Network error:'NeuralNetwork' object has no attribute 'think'

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I was interested in learning some machine learnging, so I started clicking around. I started following the instructions and created this code.

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot

class NeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self):
        # seed the genarator
        random.seed(1)
        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3,1)) - 1
    
    def __sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 /(1 + exp(-x))

    def predict(self, inputs):
        return self.__sigmoid(dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))

    def __sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        return x * (x - 1)

    def train(self, trainingSetInputs, trainingSetOutputs, numberOfIterations):
        for iteration in range(numberOfIterations):
            output = self.predict(trainingSetInputs)
            error = trainingSetOutputs - output
            adjustment = dot(trainingSetInputs.T, error * 
self.__sigmoid_derivative(output))
            self.synaptic_weights += adjustment





if __name__ == '__main__':
    # make one network
    neuralNetwork = NeuralNetwork()

    print('random starting synaptic weights')
    print(neuralNetwork.synaptic_weights)

    # training data
    trainingSetInputs = array([[0,0,1], [1,1,1], [1,0,1], [0,1,1]])
    trainingSetOutputs = array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

    #train the network 10000 times
    neuralNetwork.train(trainingSetInputs, trainingSetOutputs, 10000)

    print('new wheights')
    print(neuralNetwork.synaptic_weights)

    # test the network
    print("testing")
    print(neuralNetwork.think(array([1,0,1])))
```

I followed the instuctions to the letter, but maybe I missed something?
His tutorial is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p69khggr1Jo).

EDIT: The error I got was: 'NeuralNetwork' object has no attribute 'think'

Comment: You haven't created a method called `think()` so why should this work?

Comment: the link you posted is for youtube.... also the neural network defined does not have a `think` method, so the error is to be expected

Comment: You have forgotten to implement the `think()` method in your `NeuralNetwork()` class.

Comment: ok sorry, this was mostly my fault, I'm not the best programmer, though I'm trying to get better

Answer (score 0):

You need to create think() method. Looking at your code it should be:

```
def think(self, inputs):
    #pass inputs through our single neuron(our single neuron)
    return self.___sigmoid(dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))
```

Do this and you'll be fine!